# What causes this tearing and how to repair/avoid it?

Tags: edit-mode, sculpting

After some initial modeling if I move into sculpt mode and use various brushes, sometimes the object starts to tear apart (see below example). This has happened to me on multiple project files.

Here is the whole hand:

[image]

In this case when I start sculpting the third finger it starts to tear.

[image]

If I move back into edit mode and connect all of the edges back together and make everything nice and neat again almost immediately after starting the sculpting process the object falls back apart.

**What causes this issue and what is the process I should take to avoid/repair it?**

Using version 2.76

Comment: Seems like your mesh isn't closed, and some sculpting actions you take separating between unmerged vertices. Before you start sculpting, try to select all vertices in edit mode, then remove doubles by pressing W --> Remove doubles